# How to link to another page with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php

How do I link the following `"link" : "#mathematics"` in php to another php page named `mathematics.php`?

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('progressApp', []);

app.controller('progressBars', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.fundData = [{
            "fund": "Mathematics",
            "goal": "400",
            "raised": "389",
            "link": "#mathematics"
        }, {
            "fund": "Physics",
            "goal": "350",
            "raised": "169",
            "link": "#physics"
        }, {
            "fund": "Chemistry",
            "goal": "350",
            "raised": "203",
            "link": "#chemistry"
        }, {
            "fund": "Programming",
            "goal": "350",
            "raised": "299",
            "link": "#programming"
        }];
    }
]);</script>
```

How do I replace the `#` with the code to link to php page?

Comment: Usually, the whole point of an Angular app is to have a single-page application, where you don't navigate away (except perhaps to an external site). Just putting that into the conversation...